# Extract object from JS script loaded with synchronous jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get use an object from a script loaded synchronously using Ajax via jQuery.

From this script I am trying to load an object which looks like this from a script called `map_dropdowns.js` which returns the object `options`:

```
{curr_cat: "RELATIONSHIP"
curr_subcat: "  Population in households"
curr_total: "Total"}
```

My code for the script with the ajax is here:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../scripts/map_dropdowns.js",
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    console.log(options); //returns `Object{}` in the console, and only shows values when expanded
    options["curr_cat"]; //returns undefined
    console.log(Object.keys(options)); //returns an empty array []

</script>
```

In the original script, the keys and values within `options` can be accessed perfectly fine. `console.log` in Chrome shows its contents fully without needing to be expanded (`Object {curr_cat: "RELATIONSHIP", curr_subcat: "  Population in households", curr_total: "Total"}`), and `Object.keys()` works just fine.

After it is loaded onto the page with the Ajax function, however, trying to access the values using the keys comes up `undefined`, Object.keys turns up an empty array `[]`, and the key:value pairs are only shown in the console when I click on the object, with it otherwise showing only `Object {}`.

I am pretty sure that I need to do something in the `success` function of the Ajax, but I am not sure what after a lot of trial and error.

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, please remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice to use it; to the point where the browser actually warns you about its use in the console. Secondly, you say that `Object.keys` and other attempts to retrieve the values didn't work. Could you please edit your question to show the code you tried in those cases.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added those! Thanks. What should I use instead of `async: false` in order to make sure it's synchronous?

Comment: Thanks for that, although I'm still confused. Where is `options` defined? Also, just remove `async: false` and never ever use a synchronous request. Always use async.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's defined in the `map_dropdowns.js` script which is being loaded and returns `options`. I don't think the issue is there though since the problem only occurs after it is loaded using ajax.

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell Can you post the contents of `map_dropdowns.js` here?

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell loading external script via JS is always a bit flaky due to the security restrictions in some browsers. I'd suggest you instead return the data in JSON format, as outlined in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading JS code via AJAX is always a little hit and miss. It's usually a much better idea to load the data either as HTML, XML or JSON, and then deal with it as required once the AJAX request completes.

In your case, as you're attempting to load an object, JSON would be the most appropriate. If you change your `map_dropdowns.js` file to return data in this format:

```
'{"curr_cat":"RELATIONSHIP","curr_subcat":"Population in households","curr_total":"Total"}'
```

You can then make your async request to get this information from this file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../scripts/map_dropdowns.js",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.curr_cat); // = 'RELATIONSHIP'
        console.log(data.curr_subcat); // = 'Population in households'
        console.log(data.curr_total); // = 'Total'
    }
});
```